# Adding gulp.js to a non web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, win-universal-app

I have a UWA (Universal windows app) project where i want to use gulp.

So i added a `package.json` with the following content:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp":  "3.9.0"
    }
}
```

And it created the node_modules\gulp directory with some files.
Then i created `gulp.js` with the following content:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  console.log('Hello world!');
});
```

but the `Task Runner Explorer` just says `No task runner configurations where found.` what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename needs to be `gulpfile.js`.